# how to download daily motion video?

Tags: java, android

I am working on daily motion video downloader android application, I have got the downloading link
https://proxy-25.sg1.dailymotion.com/sec(dBG4yhTDGt8s-xJL9sczH_7xepHY7fASsEf--yb2hurT6QGlS77UybPsDxeGgwnIJAX0byvcREo9Wni-vBKPqA)/video/773/458/493854377_mp4_h264_aac_ld.mp4
but still downloading's does not stats and I am getting  this exception:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:44)
W/System.err:     at okio.Buffer.writeAll(Buffer.java:1053)
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8(RealBufferedSource.java:188)
W/System.err:     at com.androidnetworking.common.ANRequest.parseNetworkError(ANRequest.java:671)
W/System.err:     at com.androidnetworking.utils.Utils.getErrorForServerResponse(Utils.java:226)
W/System.err:     at com.androidnetworking.internal.InternalRunnable.executeDownloadRequest(InternalRunnable.java:110)
W/System.err:     at com.androidnetworking.internal.InternalRunnable.run(InternalRunnable.java:58)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err:     at com.androidnetworking.core.PriorityThreadFactory$1.run(PriorityThreadFactory.java:47)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Code

```
private void download() {
  String url = "https://proxy-25.sg1.dailymotion.com/sec" 
      + "(dBG4yhTDGt8s-xJL9sczH_7xepHY7fASsEf--yb2hurT6QGlS77UybPsDxeGgwnIJAX0byvcREo9Wni" 
      + "-vBKPqA)/video/773/458/493854377_mp4_h264_aac_ld.mp4";
  File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("") + "/DownloadFiles");
  File f = new File(folder + File.separator + "status");
  AndroidNetworking.download(url, f.getAbsolutePath(), "video" + ".mp4")
      .setTag("tag")
      .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
      .build()
      .setDownloadProgressListener(new DownloadProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(long bytesDownloaded, long totalBytes) {
  
          Log.d("downloading", "downloaded:" + bytesDownloaded + " total:" + totalBytes);
  
        }
      }).startDownload(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadComplete() {
  
        }
  
        @Override
        public void onError(ANError anError) {
          Log.d("error", "error" + anError);
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: sorry i was not allowed to insert image so i have added the exception in code instead of image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add Cookies for current Video session

because Dailymotion video M3u8/Mp4 Link not work without Cookies for current session

Comment: Welcome if my answer worked then please marked as accepted answer and upvote